# Will this work when changing all the extensions in a site from .htm to .aspx?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, seo

I have been tasked with giving my company's website (~40 pages) a facelift. The original site is written in straight html/css/javascript and every file has the .htm extension. The new site is written in .net 3.5, Hosted on windows through iis.

I am not changing the directoy structure at all, but every page will go from a .htm extension to .aspx and I am concerned about how this will effect my SEO.

From [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076615/seo-friendly-301-redirect-htm-to-aspx:) I found a link to this article detailing a custom http module from which I have the following code:

```
public class PermanentRedirectHttpModule : IHttpModule
{

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
    }

    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        HttpRequest request = context.Request;

        if (request.Url.PathAndQuery.Contains(".htm"))
        {
            string url = request.Url.ToString();
            url = url.Replace(".htm", ".aspx"); 
            context.Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently";
            context.Response.AddHeader("Location", url);
            context.Response.End(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I have implemented this method and everything works as I would expect it to. Is this method acceptable and will it maintain my search engine rankings?

Comment: Are you sure your code works?  It currently reads as: If the path and query contains ".aspx", then replace ".htm" with ".aspx".

Comment: why not change the configuration to allow the ISAPI runtime to handle the .htm extension as if it were an aspx file? Here is another good link  http://forums.asp.net/t/1741078.aspx/1?Remove+the+HTM+extension+programatically

Comment: @Lloyd, if I may, because the problem isn't physically changing the file extensions (or their type, for that matter), but preserving their page rank.

Comment: @harpo yeah, but the rewrite happens internally to the server, so externally the paths are unchanged. Am I missing something?

Comment: The link I added is a better option then

Comment: If I implement url rewriting or 301 redirection so that webiste/home.htm will bring the user to website/home.aspx will search engines maintain the .htm extension of switch to the .aspx one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work by redirecting all of your .htm paths to .aspx. Because you're doing a 301 redirect, you might notice a temporary drop in search engine places as the power gets transferred. You'll also need to make sure that any links on your site go to the new URLs, otherwise you'll get alot of internal 301 redirects.

An alternative would be to use URL rewriting. This way you could maintain your .htm URLs, but they would be rewritten to point to the .aspx pages.

Helicon ISAPI (http://www.isapirewrite.com/) is one I often use. If you just have the 1 site on the server, you can get away with using the lite (free) version.

If you're using IIS7, you could use the built in rewrites which are configured in the web.config file of your site.